# how to get Long running process completion status using WebService and Jquery AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I have created web service with uploading bulk data to the server (sql database).

*I have created two methods one for*
uploading data on server and other is for getting status from saved records it will continue monitoring UploadingData method and display status to the client at every second.

*Here is the code snippet:*

**AJAX**

```
//------------------------------
        // Save uploaded file data in database
        //------------------------------
        function SaveFileData() {
            DisplayMessage("Uploading bulk data from file to database, this will take time please wait...", "Loading", false);

            //This will try to diaplay status of saved records in database
            displayRecordStatusOn();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SaveData.asmx/SaveFileData",
                data: "{'FileName':'" + savedFileName + "', 'ClientID':'" + GetSelectedClient() + "','FileAutoID':'" + savedFileAutoID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);
                    if (result.Success == "False") {
                        DisplayMessage("Error : " + result.Message, "Failed", false);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        //DisplayMessage("Datatransfer process 100% completed", "Success", false);
                        displayRecordStatusOff();
                        DisplayMessage(result.Message, "Success", false);
                        alert("100% Done!!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

//This method called every second and get result from SaveFileData (web service method)
function displayRecordStatusOn() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SaveData.asmx/GetRecordsInsertStatus",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);
                    if (result.Success == "False") {
                        console.log("F: " + result.Message);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("S: " + result.Message);
                    }
                }
            });
            recordStatusTimer = setTimeout("displayRecordStatusOn()", 1000);
        }
```

**WEB SERVICE**

```
 string RecordStatus = "";
     [WebMethod]
            [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
            public string SaveFileData(string FileName, string ClientID, string FileAutoID)
            {
//--HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentCount"] = 0;
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("Counter" + FileAutoID);
                try
                {
                    DataTable dtExcelData = ExcelDataLoader(FileName, ClientID, "");
                    long TotalRecords = dtExcelData.Rows.Count;
                    long CopiedRecords = 0;
                    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopiedRecords = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + string.Format(DataBankTableFormat, FileAutoID) + ";", cn);
 //--HttpContext.Current.Session["TotalCount"] = TotalRecords;
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Counter" + FileAutoID, TotalRecords, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.High, null);
                        cn.Open();
                        using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
                        {
                            copy.BatchSize = BatchSize;
copy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
                        copy.NotifyAfter = BatchSize;
                            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dtExcelData.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
                            {
                                copy.ColumnMappings.Add(colIndex, colIndex);
                            }
                            copy.DestinationTableName = string.Format(DataBankTableFormat, FileAutoID);
                            copy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                            CopiedRecords = System.Convert.ToInt32(cmdCopiedRecords.ExecuteScalar());
                            RecordStatus = string.Format("{0} of {1} copied successfully!", CopiedRecords, TotalRecords);
                        }
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                    Response = GetResponse(true, RecordStatus);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response = GetResponse(false, ex.Message);
                }
                return Response;
            }
           [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetRecordsInsertStatus(string FileAutoID)
        {
            try
            {
                Response = GetResponse(true, RecordStatus(FileAutoID));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response = GetResponse(false, ex.Message);
            }
            return Response;
        }
    public string RecordStatus(string FileAutoID)
            {
                string response = "";
                //--response = string.Format("{0} of {1} copied successfully! at {2}", HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentCount"], HttpContext.Current.Session["TotalCount"], DateTime.Now.ToString());
                response = string.Format("{0} of {1} copied successfully! at {2}", HttpContext.Current.Cache["Counter" + FileAutoID] == null ? "0" : HttpContext.Current.Cache["Counter" + FileAutoID].ToString(), 786, DateTime.Now.ToString());
                //return HttpContext.Current.Cache["Counter"+ClientID] == null ? "0" : HttpContext.Current.Cache["Counter"+ClientID].ToString();
                return response;
            }
            private static void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentCount"] = e.RowsCopied;
            }
```

**Problem:**

**The code is working fine except i am not getting the value of RecordStatus variable during the SaveFileData are in process after this method (SaveFileData).**

- i have global variable RecordStatus  and i am updating it value from
  SaveFileData method and i am trying to get value from
  GetRecordsInsertStatus method to display on client browser. (but this
  is alway return blank)

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement to use an ASMX WebService? Can you use .NET 4.0 for this project? If the answer to the first question is `no` and the answer to the second question is `yes` I can show you an example using PUSH technology instead of having the client POLL using continuous AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can initialize the RecordStatus variable the way your are doing it because it will be reinstantiated every time you call a method on the web service (that's why you always get "blank").

You need to save/update the status to some sort of <s>temp</s> status table in a database on the SaveFileData method and keep reading this row constantly to return this information on the GetRecordsInsertStatus method.

**EDIT**

I just realized that you could also put this information in the Application Cache, insert it and update it in the SaveFileData method and read it from Cache in the GetRecordsInsertStatus method. No need for static classes with Hashtables when that's precisely what the application Cache is.

**EDIT 2:** I decided to implement a little sample project demonstrating what I meant on my initial answer. I think it's easy to follow.

Below is my home page with script and markup mixed:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var pool = true;
        function displayRecordStatusOn() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SaveData.asmx/GetRecordsInsertStatus",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"ClientID":"' + $('#CustomerIDs').val() + '"}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if(pool)
                        $('#status').html('Current status: '+response.d);
                }
            });
            if(pool)
                setTimeout(displayRecordStatusOn, 1000);
        }

        function SaveFileData() {
            //This will try to diaplay status of saved records in database
            pool = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SaveData.asmx/SaveFileData",
                data: '{ "FileName": "whatever.txt" , "ClientID": "'+$('#CustomerIDs').val()+'" ,"FileAutoID":"1"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d == 'Done saving file') {
                        pool = false;
                        $('#status').html(response.d);
                    }
                }
            });
            displayRecordStatusOn();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <input type="button" onclick="SaveFileData();" value="Start Upload Process" />
         <select id="CustomerIDs" >
         <option value="1">Customer 1</option>
         <option value="2">Customer 2</option>
         <option value="3">Customer 3</option>
         <option value="4">Customer 4</option>
         </select>
         <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the page initially looks like this:
[image: snaphost of page]

The web service code is the following:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string SaveFileData(string FileName, string ClientID, string FileAutoID)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("Counter"+ClientID);
        int counter = 0;
        bool process = true;
        while (process)
        {
            //This while loop executes for 10 seconds. This is so that I can simulate the long process the
            //questioner is asking
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            counter++;
            //Append ClientID to the Key so that it can be uniquely identified since it's stored in Cache. 
            //If done in Session, no need to append the ClientID
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("Counter"+ClientID, counter, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
            if (counter == 10)
                process = false;
        }
        return "Done saving file";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetRecordsInsertStatus(string ClientID)
    {
        //Added ClientID as parameter since we need to uniquely identify the key in the Cache
        return HttpContext.Current.Cache["Counter"+ClientID] == null ? "0" : HttpContext.Current.Cache["Counter"+ClientID].ToString();
    }
```

Finally, this is how everything looks together (displaying 2 concurrent users uploading files at the same time):

[image: Do I get the 50 points? :D]

Comment: You right. i would not prefer first way because it will open/close connection and increase overhead on server. so i like second way to Create Static class with HashTable, Instead of store all the details in HashTable why i am not storing only Count of saved records? other wise it may create security hall.

Comment: @imdadhusen I think you missunderstood my suggestion. I think the best approach is the 'status' table. I wouldn't be concerned about opening/closing DB connections since these things are pooled. If you dispose properly of them I don't think this is a real issue. The static class with a static Hashtable is actually very risky since you may run into Threading issues and memory leaks if you are not super/extra careful. I haven't done anything like this before so I suggest you wait for other people to comment.

Comment: i have added following line `HttpContext.Current.Cache["RecordStatus"] = string.Format("{0} of {1} copied successfully! at {2}", CopiedRecords, TotalRecords, DateTime.Now.ToString());` in **SaveFileData** and following in `return GetResponse(true, Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Cache["RecordStatus"]));` in **GetRecordsInsertStatus** but still did not getting output

Comment: @imdadhusen please see my updated answer. Finally had a little bit of time to spend implementing what I meant on my initial answer. I hope you find it easy to follow. I can provide the whole project code if you need. Just let me know.

Comment: Hi Lcarus, Thanks for constant support, but i am not getting output till date. I tried your **(Cache)** and Mrchief **(Session)** suggestions but couldn't get result.

Comment: See basically i would like to update status (1024 of 65536 copied successfully!, 2000 of 65536 copied successfully!,5000  of 65536 copied successfully! till 65536 of 65536 copied successfully!.......... but instead of i am getting only  of 65536 copied successfully!  of 65536 copied successfully!  of 65536 copied successfully! at every second when my main thred is transfering data in database and after that i got
**65536 of 65536 copied successfully!**

Comment: @imdadhusen please update your question with the latest version of your code so I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper to do this is use `SqlBulkCopy.NotifyAfter` Property. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.notifyafter.aspx):

> This property is designed for user interface components that
>   illustrate the progress of a bulk copy operation. It indicates the
>   number of rows to be processed before generating a notification event.

So, leveraging that property, I would modify your code as follows:

**Add a method to get count** (just a nicety)

```
private int GetCount(SqlConnection cn) {
    SqlCommand cmdCopiedRecords = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + string.Format(DataBankTableFormat, FileAutoID) + ";", cn);
    return System.Convert.ToInt32(cmdCopiedRecords.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

**Add a property to return formatted RecordStatus:**

```
public string RecordStatus
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} of {1} copied successfully!", Session["CurrentCount"], Session["TotalCount"]); }
}
```

**Add the event handler:**

```
private static void OnSqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
{
    Session["CurrentCount"] = (int)Session["CurrentCount"] + e.RowsCopied;
}
```

**And finally the modified `SaveFileData` method:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string SaveFileData(string FileName, string ClientID, string FileAutoID)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtExcelData = ExcelDataLoader(FileName, ClientID, "");
        long TotalRecords = dtExcelData.Rows.Count;
        long CopiedRecords = 0;
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            // NO LONGER NEEDED HERE - SqlCommand cmdCopiedRecords = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + string.Format(DataBankTableFormat, FileAutoID) + ";", cn);

            cn.Open();

            // ADDED - get an initial count
            Session["CurrentCount"] = GetCount(cn);

            // ADDED - store total
            Session["TotalCount"] = TotalRecords;

            using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(cn))
            {
                copy.BatchSize = BatchSize;

                // ADDED - Set up the event handler to notify after 50 rows.
                copy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
                copy.NotifyAfter = BatchSize;

                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dtExcelData.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
                {
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(colIndex, colIndex);
                }
                copy.DestinationTableName = string.Format(DataBankTableFormat, FileAutoID);
                copy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
        Response = GetResponse(true, RecordStatus);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response = GetResponse(false, ex.Message);
    }
    return Response;
}
```

**Notes:**

- I'm using `Session` instead of `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. This is because `Cache` is per `AppDomain` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx)). In other words, its the same for every user. So if you want to distinguish count based on users, this will give you wrong results.
- If you do have to use `HttpCache`, use `HttpRuntime.Cache` as that is bit faster than `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/06/437559.aspx) for details.

Comment: See basically i would like to update status (1024 of 65536 copied successfully!, 2000 of 65536 copied successfully!,5000  of 65536 copied successfully! till 65536 of 65536 copied successfully!.......... but instead of i am getting only  of 65536 copied successfully!  of 65536 copied successfully!  of 65536 copied successfully! at every second when my main thred is transfering data in database and after that i got
**65536 of 65536 copied successfully!**

Comment: @imdadhusen: Your updated code is mixing `Session` with `HttpCache`. I noticed several other errors too. Seems like you're mixing mine with Icarus's code. Backup your existing file, delete all the code you've and copy mine entirely (not everything in the file but only the methods we are discussing).

Comment: i agreed, but the logic for getting status would be same with Icarus code. could you please let me know what should i do for updating status i am ready to apply your code if it would giving me result. thanks for your support.